# Python - Build YAML file using .env file

Tags: python

I am having a problem with python. In my project, I have the following .env file:

```
APP_NAME=laravel-api
APP_ENV=dev
APP_KEY=
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_URL=http://localhost
APP_HOST=laravel-api
APP_PORT=9000

WEB_PORT=8000

LOG_CHANNEL=stack

DB_CONNECTION=pgsql
DB_HOST=database
DB_PORT=5432
DB_DATABASE=laravel
DB_USERNAME_SECRET=postgres
DB_PASSWORD_SECRET=postgres

BROADCAST_DRIVER=log
CACHE_DRIVER=file
QUEUE_CONNECTION=sync
SESSION_DRIVER=cookie
SESSION_LIFETIME=120

REDIS_HOST=redis
REDIS_PASSWORD_SECRET=redis
REDIS_PORT=6379

MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.mailtrap.io
MAIL_PORT=2525
MAIL_USERNAME_SECRET=null
MAIL_PASSWORD_SECRET=null
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=null

PUSHER_APP_ID=
PUSHER_APP_KEY=
PUSHER_APP_SECRET=
PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER=mt1
```

Now I want to create a yaml file out of this .env file, so I made the following method:

```
def build_yaml(component_path, tag_mapping, env_vars):    
    configmap_content = {}
    configmap_content["data"] = {}


    # Loop over each line in the env file
    for env_var in env_vars:

        env_var = env_var.strip()
        if env_var.startswith('#') or not env_var:
            continue
        
        key, value = env_var.split('=', 1)
        
        if not key.endswith('_SECRET'):
            value = str(value)
            configmap_content["data"][key] = f'"{value}"'


    yaml = ruamel.yaml.YAML()
    yaml.indent(sequence=4, offset=2)
    yaml.preserve_quotes = False

    with open(f"{component_path}/test.yaml", 'w') as f:
        yaml.dump(configmap_content, f)
```

I tried a line like this:

```
configmap_content["data"][key] = f'"{value}"'
```

To add double quotes to every variable value, but in the output file, the double quotes are surrounded by single quotes as well. One sample output line is this:

```
APP_NAME: '"laravel-api"'
```

But I want it to be:

```
APP_NAME: "laravel-api"
```

If I remove that line, the output is like this:

```
APP_NAME: laravel-api
```

Which is not what I want in my case... How can I add the double quotes only?

Comment: YAML.dump sometimes does this for its own usage, but reading the YAML should remove them. I think it's because you have a dash in the string

Comment: One other example line is `DB_DATABASE: '"laravel"'`. This has no dash in the line. This double and single quote thing can cause issues right? It needs to have quotes for values with spaces or something like that, but double and single quotes, seems invalid

Comment: What's wrong with `APP_NAME: laravel-api`? That's entirely valid YAML; it doesn't need quotes.

Comment: Oh, I am trying to build a kubernetes config, but in all examples I see every value surrounded by double quotes. Even every number as value has double quotes, so thats why I am trying to get the same result

Comment: The YAML is adding the single quotes to tell the parser that everything in contained is one item. This maybe what the kubernetes config is doing too, but idk what that is. EDIT: [This](https://codefresh.io/learn/software-deployment/kubernetes-deployment-yaml/) looks fine without the double quotes

Comment: Be careful with `... or not env_var`: this will remove boolean flags with value `False`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It might be of interest to you to use [`python-dotenv`](https://pypi.org/project/python-dotenv/) (and, if you are using `conda`, it is even in its default channel, so simply `conda install python-dotenv`).

Here is an example:

```py
txt = """
PP_NAME=laravel-api
APP_ENV=dev
APP_KEY=
APP_DEBUG=true
OTHER=false
HOST=localhost
APP_URL=http://${HOST}  # interpolation
APP_HOST=${PP_NAME}
APP_PORT=9000

# THIS=foo
THAT=foo  # comment
FOO=null
MY_SECRET=password
"""
```

We would normally have this in a file, but for the purpose of this example, let's just use `io.StringIO(txt)`.

```py
import io
from dotenv import dotenv_values

d = dotenv_values(stream=io.StringIO(txt))
>>> d
OrderedDict([('PP_NAME', 'laravel-api'),
             ('APP_ENV', 'dev'),
             ('APP_KEY', ''),
             ('APP_DEBUG', 'true'),
             ('OTHER', 'false'),
             ('HOST', 'localhost'),
             ('APP_URL', 'http://localhost'),
             ('APP_HOST', 'laravel-api'),
             ('APP_PORT', '9000'),
             ('THAT', 'foo'),
             ('FOO', 'null'),
             ('MY_SECRET', 'password')])
```

Then, to clean things up a bit further (I know k8s' config will just be happy with every value as strings, but I like the comfort that, at least during our own conversion, we parsed values into the proper type; it just increases a little bit the likelihood to having clean resulting yaml files):

```py
def totype(v):
    vl = v.lower()
    if vl in ['true', 'yes', 'false', 'no']:
        return vl in {'true', 'yes'}
    if vl in {'null', 'none'}:
        return None
    for type_ in int, float:
        try:
            return type_(v)
        except ValueError:
            pass
    return v


d = {k: totype(v) for k, v in d.items() if not k.lower().endswith('_secret') and v != ''}
>>> d
{'PP_NAME': 'laravel-api',
 'APP_ENV': 'dev',
 'APP_DEBUG': True,
 'OTHER': False,
 'HOST': 'localhost',
 'APP_URL': 'http://localhost',
 'APP_HOST': 'laravel-api',
 'APP_PORT': 9000,
 'THAT': 'foo',
 'FOO': None}
```

The resulting YAML looks fine to me:

```py
>>> print(yaml.dump(d))
APP_DEBUG: true
APP_ENV: dev
APP_HOST: laravel-api
APP_PORT: 9000
APP_URL: http://localhost
FOO: null
HOST: localhost
OTHER: false
PP_NAME: laravel-api
THAT: foo
```